# Passing a function as an argument into another function won't compile without using quotes ''?

Tags: function, matlab, function-handle

When I pass a function (let's call it `f`)  into my Base function , the Base function doesn't recognize 
the `f` function , without using `''` quotes , here's the code :

```
function y = test(a, b, n ,f)

if ( rem(n,2) ~= 0 )
   error ( 'n is not even' )
end

% create a vector of n+1 linearly spaced numbers from a to b
x = linspace ( a, b, n+1 );

for i = 1:n+1
    % store each result at index "i" in X vector
    X(i) = feval ( f, x(i) );
end
y=sum(X);
end
```

And this is `f.m` :

```
function [y] = f (x)
y = 6-6*x^5;
```

When I run from command line with quotes :

```
>> [y] = test(0,1,10,'f')

y =

   52.7505
```

but when I remove them :

```
>> [y] = test(0,1,10,f)
Error using f (line 2)
Not enough input arguments.
```

Where is my mistake ? why can't I execute `[y] = test(0,1,10,f)`  ?

Thanks

Comment: Try passing @f as the argument instead?

Comment: Your code as written, and as the error suggests, is trying to evaluate the function `f` and pass the result into the function test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function [`feval`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/feval.html) expects either the function name (i.e., a string) or a function handle as input. In your code, `f` is neither a name, nor a handle. Use either the string `'f'` or the handle `@f` when calling your base function `test`.

If, as posted in the comments, function handles are not allowed per assignment in the call to the base function, you can still use the function handle to create a string with the name of the function. This functionality is provided by the function [`func2str`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/str2func.html):

```
functionName = func2str(@f); 

test(0,1,10,functionname);
```

Comment: I can't pass `@f` (assignment rules) , I need to pass only `f` , any other suggestion maybe ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'assignment rules'? Passing `@f` is the correct thing to do here. In other words, `test.m` is fine, you need to invoke it as `test(0,1,10,@f)`.

Comment: @ron Are function handles prohibited in general or just in the call to `text()`?

Comment: @H.Muster: Just in the call of `test(...)`  . Please note that I can always do this : `q = @(x) 6*x^2 +1` and then execute `test()` like this : `test(0,1,10,q)`  with no `@` ... but when I have `q` as an `m-file` , this won't work ... see what I mean ?

Answer (score 2):

Try passing `@f` as the argument instead of `'f'`, and also change the line to

```
X(i) = f(x(i));
```

The thing is that just `f` is not a function handle. Also there's no need to use `feval` in this case.

Comment: I can't pass `@f` (assignment rules) , I need to pass only `f` , any other suggestion maybe ? thanks